# Python - Regex How to replace characters in a string?

Tags: python, regex, replace

I have tried re.search but donot know the exact syntax of regular expression to replace (anything in between) with nothing.
suppose  have the following string:

```
D08838  Acotiamide hydrochloride hydrate (JAN/BBC); Acotiamide hydrochloride (USAN) Antagonist
```

I want to get something like this:

```
D08838  Acotiamide hydrochloride hydrate; Acotiamide hydrochloride  Antagonist
```

Comment: [Here is a good tutorial](http://regular-expressions.info) to get you started on regular expressions. As for python, I find the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) quite comprehensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go for:

```
import re
s = 'D08838  Acotiamide hydrochloride hydrate (JAN/BBC); Acotiamide hydrochloride (USAN) Antagonist'
print re.sub('(\s*\(.*?\))', '', s)
#D08838  Acotiamide hydrochloride hydrate; Acotiamide hydrochloride Antagonist
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "D08838  Acotiamide hydrochloride hydrate (JAN/BBC); Acotiamide hydrochloride (USAN) Antagonist"
>>> re.sub('\s\([\w/]+\)', '', s)
'D08838  Acotiamide hydrochloride hydrate; Acotiamide hydrochloride Antagonist'
```